# BizTalk: Change schema reference before sending

Tags: xml, xsd, mapping, biztalk

The situation:

For a project we have a schema (lets call it a-forgiving) which has around 200 fields mapped in separate groups.
In this schema all fields are optional as the security rights of the caller do not allow to see all fields.

But there are also users needing the nearly same schema, lets call it a-strict, which has exactly the same fields and structure, but nothing is optional in it.

Other points:

- The schema a (strict & forgiving) are official schemas, we can not change those.
- The Security filtering is based on the data access level.

My question is:

Is there a nice & easy way to map our internal schema to both of these a-schemas?
I saw only one possibility:

1. Two mappings (from internal to a-strict and from internal to a-forgiving) => as it is exactly the same mapping (only a different target schema-name and no optional fields) it would be kind of a duplication and we would need to change both mappings if we change our internal schema.

Does anyone have a better idea or had a similar situation before?

Would be great if someone sees a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the Target Namespace for Forgiving and Strict is different, then they are different schemas.  That's how you should look at it.

They may be structurally identical, but they're still different schemas and should be treated as such.  Meaning, two Maps.